# Extract Year only from 'Select @@version' output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to automate a short task in configuring our SQL Server for which I have to grab SQL Server year. Is there a way to extract year only from the output of following query: `Select @@version` ?

As you know it outputs the whole informatioin e.g.: 
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU18) (KB4527377) - 14.0.3257.3 (X64)   Nov 16 2019 01:14:50   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

I tried the year function as below but I'm getting conversion error.

```
declare @SQLVersion varchar(100)
set @SQLVersion = (Select year(@@version))
print @SQLVersion
```

Or is there another way of grabbing the year only using tsql?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the output of version there are 4 possible years so parsing it for year can be problematic. Can you use product version instead of year: SELECT  @SQLVersion serverproperty('ProductMajorVersion') . 15= 2019, 14=2017, 13= 2016

Comment: Thank you that indeed was the right trick and found the a related answer.

Answer (score 3):

Found a related answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331621/sql-query-to-get-sql-year-version. Below code will provide year only. Credit goes to that post.

```
Declare @SQLVersion varchar(100)
Declare @TargetServer Varchar (4)
--Extract SQL Server Year 
set @SQLVersion = (SELECT
   CASE SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), SERVERPROPERTY('productversion')), 1, 2)
          WHEN '8.' THEN '2000'
          WHEN '9.' THEN '2005'
          WHEN '10' THEN '2008'
          WHEN '11' THEN '2012'
          WHEN '12' THEN '2014'
          WHEN '13' THEN '2016'
          WHEN '14' THEN '2017'
          WHEN '15' THEN '2019'
    END)
print @SQLVersion
```